# trouble when testing solidity

Tags: ethereum, solidity

```
const assert = require('assert');
const ganache = require('ganache-cli');
const Web3 = require('web3');
const web3 = new Web3(ganache.provider());
const { interface, bytecode } = require('../compile');

let accounts;
let inbox;

beforeEach(async () => {
  // Get a list of all accounts
  accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();

  // Use one of those accounts to deploy
  // the contract
  inbox = await new web3.eth.Contract(JSON.parse(interface))
    .deploy({
      data: bytecode,
      arguments: ['Hi there!']
    })
    .send({ from: accounts[0], gas: '1000000' });
});

describe('Inbox', () => {
    it('deploys a contract', () => {
    assert.ok(inbox.options.address);
  });

  it('has a default message', async () => {
    const message = await inbox.methods.message().call();
    assert.equal(message, 'Hi there!');
  });

  it('can change the message', async () => {
    await inbox.methods.setMessage('bye').send({ from: accounts[0] });
    const message = await inbox.methods.message().call();
    assert.equal(message, 'bye');
  });
});
```

after running the above code i keep getting the following  error

inbox@1.0.0 test C:\Users\user\Documents\inbox

> mocha

Inbox
    1) "before each" hook for "deploys a contract"

0 passing (98ms)
  1 failing

1) "before each" hook for "deploys a contract":
     SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0
      at JSON.parse ()
      at Context.beforeEach (test\inbox.test.js:16:44)
      at

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! inbox@1.0.0 test: `mocha`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the inbox@1.0.0 test script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2018-07-03T13_17_54_895Z-debug.log

C:\Users\user\Documents\inbox\test>

Comment: I found my error . It was in the compile file not the test file

Comment: I think there is something wrong in the ABI interface.
Could you check the interface variable that you import from compile?

https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Ethereum-Contract-ABI#json

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I changed my encoding from 'UTF-8' to 'utf8' in my compile.js file it worked.

My compile.js file looks like this

```
const path = require('path'); //for crossplatform
const fs = require('fs'); //file system
const solc = require('solc');

const inboxPath = path.resolve(__dirname, 'contracts', 'Inbox.sol');
const source = fs.readFileSync(inboxPath, 'utf8'); //change to utf8 to UTF-8

module.exports = solc.compile(source, 1).contracts[':Inbox'];
```

Comment: maybe work in old version but in my config don't

Answer (score 1):

Hi guys I am also face this issue before.
There is nothing need to change in complie.js file.
Just we need to dot the change in declaration part

like in your case :

instead of writing this
`const {interface, bytecode} = require("../compile")`

we can write  like

```
const {interface} = require("../compile")
const {bytecode} = require("../compile")
```

In this case we get the both interface and bytecode value which is exported form compile.js file.

Answer (score 0):

uninstall your current version of solidity compiler and install solidity@0.4.17 (npm install --save solc@0.4.17) and make sure in your source code you have mentioned the correct version (pragma solidity ^0.4.17).